# jira-agile-metrics command is throwing file not found error

Tags: python, jira

```
for i in pods:
 subprocess.Popen(["jira-agile-metrics", i], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
 output = subprocess.communicate()[0]
```

This code giving `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'jira-agile-metrics'`

I already installed jira-agile-metrics. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Typing `jira-agile-metrics --help` in your Terminal returns a result at this point correct?

Comment: yeah it returns a result

Comment: Is your program running in the same environment as where you installed `jira-agile-metrics`?

Comment: yeah, I installed jira-agile-metrics in the parent directory of this file.
jira-agile-metrics --help is working fine in my current directory

Comment: @BeRT2me can you help me?